# Crashplan: Disable cloud backup option permanently

Tags: backup, crashplan

I am thinking of purchasing [Crashplan](http://www.crashplan.com/) as a backup solution.
I want to back up my computer to a different local computer on the LAN and to a friends computer offsite. I do not want to use Crashplan's cloud backup as I do not trust them to secure my data (I don't want them to see my data).

My question is:

- Is there a way to turn off Crashplan's cloud backup and still backup my computer localy and to a friends offsite backup location?

[Edit] I have downloaded the trial version and It does appear to be an option to disable the cloud backup for a single session but not permanently. I have contacted Crashplan a few days ago and not gotten a response.

Comment: Why did you down vote my questions? please add a comment so I can improve in the future.

Comment: I'm going to guess the down-vote came due to a perceived lack of research on your part.  Have you checked with Crashplan?  Why not just go [get the trial](http://www.crashplan.com/consumer/download.html) and try it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been using CrashPlan for a couple years. There is no requirement to turn on the Cloud backup - in fact if you don't pay for it, you won't have it. So no need to "disable" it. Just set it to backup to your local computers/devices or a friends and not to the CP servers.

Comment: A confusion arises because on a new install the *Crashplan Central* backup destination is shown as a green button, as the 30 day free trial is active, and can't be removed or disabled (turned grey). This makes it look as if you're going to back up to cloud no matter what. However if you go in to *Settings >> Destinations* then for each set there are check boxes to turn on/off Folders, Crashplan Central, Other Computers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It does not provide an option to cancel the cloud backup while you are in the first 30 days after installing Crashplan from what I can see.